# Swift - UIAlertController not showing up anything

Tags: ios, swift

What have I done wrong? I have tested this on iOS 8.1 simulator and iPod Tocuh 5G with iOS 8.1.

```
var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Also save this picture?", message: "Adding this picture to your Camera Roll might be a good idea.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                     UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(takenImage, nil, nil, nil)
                }))
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: did you got anything in console?

Comment: Have add any navigation controller to your project?

Comment: I have added your code in a sample project and embed the viewcontroller in a navigation controller in storyboard the alert is showing up

Comment: Where are you putting this code? Are you sure it's being run? I doubt this has anything to do with `UINavigationController`

Comment: I have the same problem intermittently, but it goes away when quitting Xcode and the simulator. Anybody else seeing ths? The code is actual Apple sample code, so it's unlikly to be a coding error.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I couldn't get UIAlertControllers to show up unless I embedded the view in a navigation controller (so using Xcode 6's default "single view" template could set it up for you like this).